# How do I restore DLC content in Oblivion Game of the Year edition?

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have the Oblivion Game of the Year bought from Steam, and have been playing with the Frostcrag Spire DLC. I bought all the upgrades, but now it has disappeared from my map entirely.

It is still showing that I have the files, and I checked the integrity of the files from Steam. Any idea how I get it back?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Steam/your pc? I once had a similar problem and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When launching Oblivion (or Skyrim/Fallout for that matter), the games usually load into a Launcher window. This window gives you some basic options for the games, like video/audio quality settings, support links, and most importantly here, **Data Files.**

Click into Data Files, and you will see a list of all .esm and .esp files that are being loaded into Oblivion. This is called your **Load Order**. Make sure that all necessary files are check-marked, including Frostcrag Spire. It would not surprise me if the game deselected it for some reason.